# Reading numbers then letters in a text file in C++

Tags: c++, string, file, input

I'm trying to do something in C++ and I'm having a little bit of trouble figuring out exactly how to do it.

I have a text file that contains information that I need to parse and act on. The format of the file is multiple lines, each containing a number followed by a letter:

```
1234 A
5678 B
9101 C
```

What I need to do is, line by line, read the number and do a calculation based on it. Then I need to do an operation depending on the value of the letter on that line. Once both operations are finished, I repeat with the next line until all lines from the file have been parsed.

I've found some articles on how to read into strings line by line, but I can't quote figure out how to separate the lines into number and letter.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example might help:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  std::ifstream fp("input.dat");

  char ch;
  int n;
  while (fp >> n && fp >> ch)
  {
    std::cout << "Here is your number: " << n << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Here is your char: " << ch << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

In the above, the file `input.dat` contains your input.  This example doesn't care if numbers and letters are separated by newlines, tabs, spaces or any other whitespace.  If you really need to ready a particular format you could look into `fscanf` or `std::getline` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/).

Answer (score 0):

```
using namespace std;

ifstream file("file.txt");
int number;
char character;

while( file >> number >> character ) {
    // read each line as a number followed by a character
    cout << number << " " << character << endl;
    switch( character ) {
        case 'A':

            break;
        case 'B':

            break;
        case 'C':

            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose some people might find luring a beginner into wiping out a file system hillarious. Surely you were too smart to fall for that when you were one, Mr Dai...